# Is $C(\mathbb R) \subset H_{s}^{loc}$ (localized Sobolev space)?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

We put, Sobolev space
$$H_{s}=H_{s}(\mathbb R)=\{f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R):[\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2}(1+|\xi|^{2})^{s}d\xi]^{1/2}<\infty \}.$$
If $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R,$ the localized Sobolev space $H_{s}^{loc}$ is the set of all distributions $f\in \mathcal{D'}(U)$ such that for every precompact open set $V$ with $\overline{V}\subset U$ there exists $g\in H_{s}$ such that $g=f$ on $V.$

**Fact**. A distribution $f\in \mathcal{D'}$ is in $H_{s}^{loc}(U)$ iff  $\phi f \in H_{s}$ for every $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(U).$
(where, $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)=$ The space space of $C^{\infty}$ functions whose support is compact)

We put, $C(\mathbb R)=$ The space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R.$

> **My Question is**: Let $s>3/2.$ Is it true that $C(\mathbb R)\subset H_{s}^{loc}$ ? If not, for which $s>0,$ one can expect this ?

Answer (score 1):

Functions in $H_1$ are absolutely continuous (or more precisely have representatives that are absolutely continuous). Since $H_s^{loc} \subset H_1^{loc}$ for $s > 1$ an affirmative answer to your question would imply that functions in $C(\mathbb R)$ have AC representatives, which they do not.

Comment: Thanks; But I could not follow you; would you pleases tell me bit more ?

Comment: I guess, you are saying answer is negative; (but I don't see how does it follow from your arguments)

Comment: It is not true that $C(\mathbb R) \subset H_1^{loc}$ because functions in the Sobolev space possess weak derivatives; functions in $C(\mathbb R)$ do not.

Comment: @Inquisitive, all functions with an $L^1$ weak derivative are absolutely continuous. Since all functions in $H_1^{loc}$ are thus (locally) absolutely continuous, but not all continuous functions are, the inclusion must fail for all $s\geq1$. But this doesn't say that the inclusion should fail for $s<1$. Your inclusion is true for $s=0$.