# Which functions lies in $H^{loc}_{s}\setminus H_{s}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, intuition, sobolev-spaces

We put $H^{s}=$The Sobolev spaces, and $H^{loc}_{s}=$The [localized Sobolev spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906006/is-c-mathbb-r-subset-h-sloc-localized-sobolev-space).

We note that, $H_{s}\subset H^{loc}_{s};$ also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906006/is-c-mathbb-r-subset-h-sloc-localized-sobolev-space). Bit roughly speaking, I am interested in knowing that how big $H^{loc}_{s}$ can be than $H_{s}.$

**My  Questions are**:

> (1) How we find few examples of functions $f$ so that $f\in H^{loc}$ but $f\notin H_{s}$ ?
>
> (2) Can we think of some well-known function space say $E,$ so that $E\subset H^{loc}\setminus H_{s}$? What is $H^{loc}_{s}\setminus H_{s}$(= The space of functions which belongs to localized Sobolev space $H^{loc}_{s}$, but not in Sobolev space $H_{s}$ ) intuitively ? Furthermore, Can we characterize the set $H^{loc}_{s}\setminus H_{s}$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: Intuitively, a function belongs to $H_s^{\mathrm{loc}}$ if it is smooth enough. For also belonging to $H^s$, a certain decay condition has to be satisfied (e.g. for $s\geq0$, we easily see $H^s \hookrightarrow L^2$). Thus, a smooth function with no decay like $x \mapsto e^{x^2}$ belongs to $H^s_{\rm{loc}}$ for all $s$, because $e^{x^2} \cdot \varphi \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$, but will probably not belong to any $H^s$ (surely not for $s \geq 0$).

Comment: @PhoemueX; thanks; are you saying $e^{x^{2}}\in H^{s}_{loc}$ for some $s>0$ ?

Comment: Why is it true that $e^{x^{2}}\phi \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ ? Can you just indicates the ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Because $e^{x^2}\varphi \in C_c^\infty \subset \mathcal{S}$. This implies $\widehat{e^{x^2}\varphi} \in \mathcal{S}$, which easily shows that the integral in the definition of $H^s$ is finite.

Comment: More generally, the same argument shows $C^\infty \subset H^s_{\mathrm{loc}}$ for all $s$.

Answer (score 3):

1. The only difference between $H^s_{\rm loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ is the decay at infinity (of the function itself, and appropriate derivatives). So, if you want functions to not belong to $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$, make them not decay at infinity. Adding a nonzero constant will do the trick. Or add a polynomial, etc.
2. Yes: the space of smooth periodic functions, $C^k_{\rm per}(\mathbb R)$ [with some period $L$], and its analogues in higher dimensions. If $k\ge s$, these are  in $H^s_{\rm loc}$, but do not contain any elements of $H^s$ other than the zero function.

> Can we characterize the set...

Sure: a function belongs to this set if it belongs to $H^s_{\rm loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ but does not belong to $H^s_{ }(\mathbb R^n)$. What simpler characterization could there be? It says exactly what is in the space.

> intuitively

[People use the word *intuition* for the most strange things](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8972359#8972359)