# Does anybody recognize the original PDE's question?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

There was a popular image going around on the internet a while back:

[image: Math problem]

Of course, $ = 1$ and $ = 2$.  As for the non-trivial part, $H^{2}_{\text{loc}}(U)$ is a [localized Sobolev space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/917875/81360) and I suppose the rest of the notation is fairly standard.  Presumably, $L^{-1/12}$ is supposed to be $L^\infty$, but $\infty$ was replaced with $- \frac 1{12}$ in reference to the Ramanujan summation result $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$.

I have two questions:

- Does anybody recognize the source of this question?  I suspect that it was lifted verbatim (up to emoji-substitutions) from a textbook.
- Does anybody have an answer to the question?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Without additional assumptions on the matrix $(a^{ij})$, this is just wrong (take $a=b=c=f=0$ and any $u\in H^1(U)\setminus H^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(U)$). If you assume that $(a^{ij})$ is positive-definite at every point, then this is a classical alliptic regularity result. You can find a proof in every introductory book on elliptic PDEs (certainly too long for an MSE answer).

Comment: @MaoWao in that case, I think the name of a popular intro text on elliptic PDE's would suffice as an answer

Comment: @BenGrossmann this is almost surely from Evan's book on PDEs. Possibly chapter 6 on Elliptic regularity.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment, this (with further assumptions on $A$) is a standard elliptic regularity result.  We should be able to find a proof in an introductory reference such as *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations* by Qing Han and FangHua Lin.